# Pass parameter with Html.ActionLink based upon value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my website with paging and search options i have to redirect the user and pass the search options. With this action I don't want to pass the search model with the URL (ex. http://localhost:1234/?Project.Models.TestModel=....).

My actionlink right now is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", new { idtrips = Model.idTrips, inituser = Model.initUser, date = Model.date.ToString("ddMMyyyy"), page = i})
```

When clicked this results in a following header: 
http://localhost:58763/?idtrips=0&inituser=0&date=05042016&page=5

**My question is:**
Can you somehow add if clauses to the Html.ActionLink to only give values if they are needed. For example I only have a date set, then I want the Url to be: http://localhost:58763/?date=05042016&page=5. The other values have a default value in my controller so this url will work but i'm not able to generate it.

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(long idtrips = 0, long inituser = 0, string date = "", int page = 1)
    { ... }
```

What i'm looking for is something like this,:

```
@Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), "Index", new { if(Model.idTrips > 0) { idtrips = Model.idTrips,} page = i})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably accomplish this with a [ternary statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (e.g. an inline-if statement) :

```
new { idtrips = Model.idTrips > 0 ? Model.IdTrips : 0, page = i}
```

Since you have a default parameter value for `idtrips`, this should only set it to something else if it is greater than 0.

If you don't want the value to appear at all, you could consider simply making it a nullable long `long?` parameter (and ensure this matches on your Model as well):

```
public ActionResult Index(long? idtrips = 0, ... ) { ... }
```

Using this approach, you could simply set it as expected :

```
new { idtrips = Model.idTrips, page = i}
```

And if `Model.idTrips` was null (e.g. the default value), then it would point to :

```
Controller/Index?page=1
```

However, if it was any non-null value, it would render the querystring parameter as expected :

```
Controller/Index?idtrips=42&page=1
```

Comment: But this still will give me the URL "http://localhost:1234/?Idtrips=0&page=5" 
And that is what I want to avoid. it should be like new { page = 5 } or new { Idtrips = 1, page = 5 } and inline. not with an if or switch statement over the Html.ActionLink

Comment: You may want to consider making your `idtrips` parameter nullable (and nullable on your Model). This would give you the intended effect that you are looking for (i.e. no display of your `idtrips` parameter when null, although it would default to 0, and it would otherwise display the parameter).

Comment: I changed them to nullable values and it works how I want. Thank you for your fast help!